# after loading a div, dialog box jquery ui wont open again

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dialog, reload

I have a list of survey results in a table. Each entry has an EDIT button, which opens a dialog box with the survey results loaded from the database, when clicked. After editing the answers, I want to click on the SAVE button in the dialog box, then save the edited answers in the database and **only** refresh the survey results table on my site.

When I reload the whole page, everything works fine, but when I try to refresh only the table, I can't open the dialog boxes any more by clicking the EDIT button.

Here's my code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('body').on('click', '.edit_button', function () {
$("#dialog").dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    width: 'auto',        
    buttons: {
        SAVE: function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "admin/ajaxMethod/" + id,
                data: $('form.cForma1').serialize(),
                success: function () {                        
                    alert("success");

                    $("#tabela").load(location.href + " #tabela");
                    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                },                    
            });
        },
        CANCEL: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");                
        },            
    }
});
});
});
```

When I put `location.reload();` instead of `$("#tabela").load(location.href + " #tabela"); $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );` then everything works, but I need only one div to reload-table div.

Comment: If edit buttons are inside table then jquery event binding will go away on table refresh function bind the edit buttons event again.

Comment: @Neha - How to do that? tnx!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on http://jsbin.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding your event to your button via `$('yourEDITbutton').click(..)` in your page.

Your `javascript` code does not work any longer, because your buttons are dynamically created and `.click(..)` **doesn't** work for dynamically created elements. The solution here would be the following:

```
$('body').on('click', '.yourEDITbuttonClass', function () {
    // Open your dialog box here
});
```

For a longer explanation see [jQuery documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I edited my code, and I tried with your code but still it's not working! tnx!

Comment: Regarding your updated code, it does *not* work because you are binding the click event to your button via `.click()`. This technique does not work with dynamically loaded elements, as stated in my answer above. How have you tried to implement my proposed solution?

Comment: It's not edited, I just replace this line `$( ".edit_button" ).click(function() {` with `$('body').on('click',  '.edit_button', function () {` and it's not working!

Comment: Doesn't it work in general or does it work before reloading but no longer after using `.load()`?

Comment: Just like I didn't change anything, it works for the first time and then again it won't work, when I click on edit button for the second time nothing happens

Comment: Could you please reproduce your problem in a jsfiddle on http://www.jsfiddle.net? As far as I can see, everything should work and maybe the mistake does only occur with your html code..

Comment: Yea, ok, I will try to narrow my code and write it in jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: I am trying to put my code in jsfiddle.net, but I don't know what to put for my url in ajax :/ _embarrassing_

Comment: something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qnnHK/), but dialog box wont fire up because of the url in ajax

Comment: ouu, yea, you were right, I just needed to change my code in two places, not just one, thank you!!

Comment: I don't know which to choose as correct, both of you were right!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a classic jQuery event binding error:

You bind the dialog to a click on the "Edit" buttons. Then you reload the table and the former event binding is gone. You either need to bind the click events again or bind the event to a element on the page which is not reloaded, something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_button', function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({ ... });
});
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code or better yet provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which shows the error?

Comment: My code is based on this one [link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form), except when clicked on their button "Create an account", their table "Existing Users" is refreshed, not the whole page

Comment: I mean, I am trying to do that, to only refresh my table "Surveys", like they refresh only "Existing Users"

Comment: It should work with my suggested change to your code. I don't think I can to more without access to your page to see the error live.

Comment: something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qnnHK/), but dialog box wont fire up because of the url in ajax

Comment: ouu, yea, you were right, I just needed to change my code in two places, not just one, thank you!!

Comment: I don't know which to choose as correct, both of you were right!